# Intellij 13.1.3 import project from sbt not working

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have followed the instructions , attempting to either import from build.sbt or open project from build.sbt.

The end result is that the scala libraries are not imported as shown in the screenshot.

I have also tried sbt gen-idea from the command line.

This is just a problem that keeps surfacing..[image]

Comment: Could you share your build.sbt and maybe the generated project files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I STILL have not figured out what the "magic" sequence of actions to follow in order to have  a reliable sbt build.

This time around the following worked:

TWICE running

```
sbt gen-idea
```

- and then import'ing the build.sbt as a new scala project

What did *not* work

- Import project from build.sbt  (without sbt gen-idea)
- Open project from build.sbt   (ditto)
- Open build.sbt from Explorer (selecting IJ to open it)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intellij, why don't you create scala sbt project? Then just add the libraries in the build.sbt and refresh the project or re-run the sbt gen-idea. The libraries will appear. See this link:
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+SBT

Comment: I have done this a couple of dozen times.  It is very flaky.  This was one of the instances that  it did not work: after refreshes, rebuilds, whatever.

Comment: Could you paste your build.sbt? By the way sometimes you may need to do: sbt clean.
Here is a list of some useful commands:
http://scala.micronauticsresearch.com/sbt/useful-sbt-commands

Comment: re: sbt clean. Yes, that was certainly required and it was done .. twice..   re:  build.sbt I will post it in a couple of hours (laptop battery died..)